# Classes in C++ and Printing Char

Tags: c++, class, char, cout

I know must be missing something obvious but I still have a lot of trouble understanding classes. I have a pointer and I'm sure that's wrong, but I don't know how. Also, when I try to print one of the variables it only displays the first char instead of both and I don't know how to fix that.

```
class Pieces
{
    public:
        char P1;
        char P2;
        char P3;
        char P4;
        char P5;
        char P6;
        char P7;
        char P8;
        char P9;
        void Board(char P1, char P2, char P3, char P4, char P5, char P6, char P7, char P8, char P9);
        void Board();
        
};

void Pieces::Board()
{
    cout << "    A   B   C \n";
    cout << " 1  B1  B2  B3\n";
    cout << " 2  .   .   . \n";
    cout << " 3  W1  W2  W3\n";
}

void Pieces::Board(char P1, char P2, char P3, char P4, char P5, char P6, char P7, char P8, char P9)
{
    cout << "    A   B   C \n";
    //cout << " 1  ", P1, "  ", P2, "  ", P3, "\n";
    cout << P1;
    cout << P1;
    cout << "\n";
    //cout << " 2  ", P4, "  ", P5, "  ", P6, "\n";
    //cout << " 3  ", P7, "  ", P8, "  ", P9, "\n";
}

int main()
{
    Pieces IDK;
    IDK.P1 = *"B1";
    IDK.P2 = *"B2";
    IDK.P3 = *"B3";
    IDK.P4 = *". ";
    IDK.P5 = *". ";
    IDK.P6 = *". ";
    IDK.P7 = *"W1";
    IDK.P8 = *"W2";
    IDK.P9 = *"W3";

    cout << IDK.P1;

    IDK.Board();
    IDK.Board(IDK.P1, IDK.P2, IDK.P3, IDK.P4, IDK.P5, IDK.P6, IDK.P7, IDK.P8, IDK.P9);
}
```

Comment: what is the code supposed to do? What is the expected output? What is the actual output?

Comment: note that `char` is a single character not a string, what do you expect `*"B1"` to do?

Comment: `IDK.P1 = *"B1";` assignes the char 'B'  to the member P1. Instead of `*arr` you can always write `arr[0]` if arr is an array variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to make this quite simple:

```
IDK.P1 = *"B1";
```

In this line, you assign several characters to a single character. `P1` is of type `char`, which holds exactly one character. `char` is a type that holds a single byte, meant to be one ASCII-encoded character. B1 are two characters.

In C-style programming, you'd use a char array that has deprecated to a pointer (`char*`) to hold several characters. It would be an array (several values that are consecutive in the memory) which ends with the terminating symbol (`\0`).
But note that I wrote C-style for a reason - in C++, you wouldn't use it.

Now, as for the syntax `*"B1"`, what this does is this: `"B1"` starts as a pointer to a char array. The star dereferences that pointer. Since a pointer to an array points to the first element of it, dereferencing gives you exactly that element, which holds the value B in your case.
Syntax like this is highly unusual, and I have no idea how you came to use it.

In any case, storing two characters in a single `char` can't be done.
You probably want to simply go by

```
std::string P1;
```

in your class, and assign it like

```
IDK.P1 = "B1";
```

---

Another thing I noticed is that your method

```
void Pieces::Board(char P1, char P2, char P3, char P4, char P5, char P6, char P7, char P8, char P9)
{
    cout << "    A   B   C \n";
    //cout << " 1  ", P1, "  ", P2, "  ", P3, "\n";
    cout << P1;
    cout << P1;
    cout << "\n";
    //cout << " 2  ", P4, "  ", P5, "  ", P6, "\n";
    //cout << " 3  ", P7, "  ", P8, "  ", P9, "\n";
}
```

does not assign any values. The parameters it takes in are forgotten after the invocation. It does *not* change the member variables of your class. I suspect that you seem to think that same name = overtaken, if so, that is not the case.

---

As for this:

```
    char P1;
    char P2;
    char P3;
    char P4;
    char P5;
    char P6;
    char P7;
    char P8;
    char P9;
```

If you write a program and you find that you do something very repetitive, like this, then usually you are doing it in a cumbersome way.
In this case, you could have simply used an array:

```
std::array<char, 9> P;
```

and then address it like

```
Pieces pieces;
pieces.P.at(0) = 'a';
```

---

```
IDK.Board(IDK.P1, IDK.P2, IDK.P3, IDK.P4, IDK.P5, IDK.P6, IDK.P7, IDK.P8, IDK.P9);
```

This line is another thing that is quite odd about your code. You call the object with it's own member variables. It already *knows* it's own members. Also, `Board` is a bad name for something that prints data. Name it after the action is does. Try this:

void Pieces::print_board()
{
cout << "    A   B   C \n";
cout << " 1  " << P1 << "  " << P2 << "  " << P3 << "\n";
cout << " 2  " << P4 << "  " << P5 << "  " << P6 << "\n";
cout << " 3  " << P7 << "  " << P8 << "  " << P9 << "\n";
}

(I also replaced the commas with stream operators here.)

---

Here is a rework of your code:

```
class Board // I renamed it to Board, because that is what it represents
{
public:

    Board() {} 
    // constructor that already takes in the state of the board,
    // using a member initializer list,
    // see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor
    Board(const std::array<std::string, 9>& pieces) : pieces(pieces) {} 
    void print() const; // if something prints, let's name it like that

    std::array<std::string, 9> pieces;  
};

void Board::print() const
{
    // I use for-loops here because while you could do your block right now,
    // it would become really cumbersome in a bigger grid
    
    cout << "    A   B   C \n";
    for(size_t i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        cout << " " << (i+1) << "  ";
        for(size_t j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            cout << pieces.at(i*3+j) << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Board board({"B1", "B2", "B3", ". ", ". ", ". ", "W1", "W2", "W3"});
    board.print();

    /* alternatively:
    Board board;
    board.pieces.at(0) = "B1";
    ...
    board.print();
    */
}
```

(Give it a run: http://www.cpp.sh/4vv3s)

Note that we might want to add a check whether all "pieces" have length two, as otherwise the printing gets misaligned. Or better, use a proper type for the pieces, like an [enum class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum), and a function that transforms a value of that into a string.

Since the pieces form a grid, we might want to use a two-dimensional array instead, `std::array<std::array<std::string, 3>, 3> pieces;`, with accessors like `board.pieces.at(0).at(0) = "B1";`. But I left that out for now.

If you need dynamic size, use `std::vector` instead of `std::array`.

Comment: Thanks, sorry my syntax is bad. I've been really confused about pointers and just wanna go back to R but that's not how the major requirements go

Comment: @KatieOsadczuk Yes, pointers can easily be quite confusing when you use them the first time. They are also very very useful and after using them a bit quite easy to understand. Although in your case, this is not the normal way to get into pointers. Char arrays are a very specific thing, and not a good start into pointers. My advice is to try writing some pointer structures as an exercise, like a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

char is simply put a single character. If you want multiple characters, you can use either a char array or `std::string`. When you use double quotations `"AB"` it indicates a const char* or constant character array. You can only keep a single character or 1byte worth of data in a char type variable. That's why you are seeing only first character. You describe a char with single quotations `'A'`.

Answer (score 0):

in Board Function

```
cout << P1
cout << P2
cout << P3
```

do it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not gonna talk about the typo as there's already other answers addressing it, I'm going to focus on the biggest problem for me: you're not using classes right.

The point of a class is to have "things that can do stuff all by themselves" so you shouldn't give them all the data they need constantly, you want to give the data once and then never have to think about it again. For your application, you could structure your class like this:

1. Define a class that can remember P1..9
2. Define a constructor for that class where you give it all it's data
3. Define methods for that class so you can print the data already inside of it

It could look something like this:

```
#include <string>

class Board
{
    public:
        Board();
        Board(char P1, char P2, char P3, char P4, char P5, char P6, char P7, char P8, char P9);
        void printBoard();

    private:
        char P1;
        char P2;
        char P3;
        char P4;
        char P5;
        char P6;
        char P7;
        char P8;
        char P9;
};

Board::Board()
{
    P1 = P2 = P3 = P4 = P5 = P6 = P7 = P8 = P9 = 0;
}

Board::Board(char piece1, char piece2, char piece3, char piece4, char piece5, char piece6, char piece7, char piece8, char piece9)
{
    P1 = piece1;
    P2 = piece2;
    P3 = piece3;
    P4 = piece4;
    P5 = piece5;
    P6 = piece6;
    P7 = piece7;
    P8 = piece8;
    P9 = piece9;
}

void Board::printBoard()
{
    std::string val;

    cout << "    A   B   C \n";

    val = " 1  ";
    if(P1 == 0)
        val += "B1";
    else
        val += std::to_string(P1);

    if(P2 == 0)
        val += "B2";
    else
        val += std::to_string(P2);

    if(P3 == 0)
        val += "B3";
    else
        val += std::to_string(P3);

    val += '\n';
    cout << val;


    val = " 2  ";
    if(P4 == 0)
        val += ". ";
    else
        val += std::to_string(P4);

    if(P5 == 0)
        val += ". ";
    else
        val += std::to_string(P5);

    if(P6 == 0)
        val += ". ";
    else
        val += std::to_string(P6);

    val += '\n';
    cout << val;


    val = " 3  ";
    if(P7 == 0)
        val += "W1";
    else
        val += std::to_string(P7);

    if(P8 == 0)
        val += "W2";
    else
        val += std::to_string(P8);

    if(P9 == 0)
        val += "W3";
    else
        val += std::to_string(P9);

    val += '\n';
    cout << val;
}
```

and then you'd use it like this:

```
int main ()
{
    Board a;
    Board b('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i');

    a.printBoard();
    b.printBoard();

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Even though I used your way of doing it, note that char arrays or std::string objects could make the code a lot shorter and easier to manage.